# ^P not working in zsh, where should I look at?

Tags: zsh

I copied my bashrc and start tweaking it for zsh, but I suddenly found `^P` wasn't functioning,

It just print a `^P` on screen.

What could be wrong? Or where should I look at now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using vi-like key-bindings in zsh without knowing it.

Zsh chooses the default keyboard mode by looking at $VISUAL and $EDITOR. If those look vi-ish (like "vim"), it'll choose vi-like bindings instead of emacs-like bindings.

`C-p` is a binding that's only in the emacs-like key-table by default. You're obviously free to bind keys to whatever you like in the vi-like key-tables as well, as "int" suggested. But chances are, that you really want emacs mode instead, which you can achieve by doing the following somewhere in your configuration:

```
bindkey -e
```

...preferably before you're doing other keyboard-related configuration.

As always, full details about zsh's line editor (zle) can be found in [the corresponding section of zsh's reference manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html). It describes how the default mode is chosen, as well as which actions are bound to what keys by default in the different key-maps.

Comment: Yeah, I set EDITOR to vim, and I was wondering why all default keybinds are gone, +1 for mentioning `-e`

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
bindkey "^P" up-line-or-history
```